# Trying to display mySQL data from a randomly selected id

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a table that contains 3 fields: an ID, a title and a body.  I'm trying to randomly select an id and then display the title and body of that record.  I don't get any errors when I preview the page but I also see nothing on the page.  I'm very new to PHP and mySQL and I'm trying to figure out what's causing this.  Thanks for any insight.

```
`$con = mysql_connect("x","x","x");
    if (!$con) {
      die ("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("haipoos", $con);

//select a random id
$randHaipoo = "SELECT 'id' FROM `haikus` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;";

//select the entire record based on random id
$selectHaipoo = "SELECT * FROM 'haikus' WHERE 'id' = '$randHaipoo'";

//store query results
$haipoo = mysql_query($selectHaipoo, $con);

//display query results
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($haipoo)){
    echo $record['title'];
    echo $record['body'];
}`
```

Comment: You need to turn on error reporting so you can see what is failing. There are a number of references on here for how to do that.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM \`haikus\` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: `WHERE 'id' = '$randHaipoo'`
remove the quotes around `id`

Comment: For the *love* of all that is *good* and *beautiful* in this world, don't use the deprecated `mysql_` interface! For new development, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Spencer (I read your comment in Chris Farley's voice).  I will heed your advice.  Turns out the issue was the ' ' around the field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
//select a random id
$selectHaipoo = "SELECT * FROM `haikus` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;";

//select the entire record based on random id
//$selectHaipoo = "SELECT * FROM 'haikus' WHERE 'id' = '$randHaipoo'";
```

And @spencer7593 is absolutely right, follow his advice in your next step of knowledge